# Problem in Expanding/Collapsing ribbon in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, ribbon, devexpress-windows-ui

I am using Elegant.UI.Ribbon (v 4.2.0.0) controls in my C# winform application. When user clicks on a page, the page will be opened in a new tab:

```
DevExpress.XtraTab.XtraTabPage TabPage = new DevExpress.XtraTab.XtraTabPage();

ImagingFutureTurn _Form1 = new ImagingFutureTurn();
_Form1.TopLevel = false;
TabPage.Text = _Form1.Text;
TabPage.Controls.Add(_Form1);
TabPage.ShowCloseButton = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
_Form1.Tag = TabPage;
ChildTab.TabPages.Add(TabPage);
ChildTab.SelectedTabPage = TabPage;

_Form1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
_Form1.Show();
```

The problem is that when expanding/collapsing Ribbon control, open forms in tab pages get messed up.
Here is my opened page:

[image]

If the form is already open and I collapse the ribbon, there would be extra space at the bottom of the page:

[image]

And if the form is already open and I expand the ribbon, I will miss the bottom of the form:

[image]

What should I do?
I have tried to change the height of the `TabPage`:

```
TabPage.Height = TabPage.Height - 111;
```

but the height won't change.

Comment: Set `_Form1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;`

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič, it is already set to fill. The problem is it doesn't get dynamically updated when expanding.collapsing ribbon.

Comment: It defiently an anchor/docking issue. Check these properties for controls on the form.